# Sage Pay (Server) throwing error at checkout

Tags: cartthrob, payment-gateway, sagepay

I've set up CartThrob and using Sage Pay (server) to process payments.
Using the {exp:cartthrob:checkout_form} tags once billing address details are added and the form is submitted I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Cartthrob_sage_s::$tokenhost
Filename: payment_gateways/Cartthrob_sage_s.php
Line Number: 469
```

I cannot find any examples of this issue on the CartThrob forums or here so wondering if there are any ideas how to resolve.

Cole

Comment: Worth mentioning that am using CartThrob in conjunction with the CT Subscriptions module

Comment: Okay - have contacted Sage Pay and tokens need to be activated on the account. Having been activated am no longer getting the above error but am getting the following error:

`<url> malformed (3)`

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with accepting tokens with a test gateway.
This has now been resolved.